# For $I$ a bounded real interval, do we have that $L^1(I) \subsetneq L^2(I)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $I$ be a bounded real interval. Then we have that $L^1(I) \subset L^2(I)$ due to the following:

> [image]

But is there an example of an $f \in L^2(I)$ that is not also in $L^1(I)$? That is, do we have that

$$
L^1(I) \subsetneq L^2(I)?
$$

And if so, why?

Comment: If $f\in L^2(I)$ for a finite interval, then $f\in L^1$ because $|f| \le \frac{1}{2}(|f|^2+1)$. So the answer to this question is "no": "is there an example of an $f\in L^2(I)$ that is not also in $L^1(I)$?"

Comment: So $L^2(I) = L^1(I)$?

Comment: No, they're not the same. There are functions in $L^1(I)$ which are not in $L^2(I)$. In other words, this is a false inclusion for a finite interval: $L^1(I)\subseteq L^2(I)$. $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x}$ is an example of $f\in L^1(I)$ which is not in $L^2(I)$, where $I=[0,1]$.

Comment: So in conclusion: $L^2(I) \subsetneq L^1(I)$?

Comment: I see that $1/\sqrt{x}$ is a counter-example to the idea that $L^1(I) \subset L^2(I)$, but then what about the proof provided in my question?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Are you sure? In any event, the proof in my original post assumes that $f$ is bounded by some $M$, which $1/\sqrt{x}$ is not.

Comment: For example, $2|AB| \le |A|^2+|B|^2$ shows that $2|A| \le |A|^2+1$. So, if $A \in L^2$, then $A \in L^1$, at least on a finite interval where $1$ is integrable. A similar interpolation holds for other exponents.

Answer (score 0):

The graph of the exponential is convex, meaning that
$$
           e^{rx+(1-r)y} \le re^{x}+(1-r)e^{y},\;\; 0 \le r \le 1.
$$
(Draw a picture and you're see it.) It follows that
$$
                 X^{r} Y^{1-r} \le rX+(1-r)Y, \;\; X,Y \ge 0,\;\; 0 \le r \le 1.
$$
Setting $Y=1$ gives
$$
                 X^{r} \le rX+(1-r)1, \;\;\; 0 \le r \le 1.
$$
So, if $X$ is absolutely integrable on a finite interval, then so is $X^r$ for every $0 < r < 1$. So, for example, $L^2 \subseteq L^p$ for all $1 \le p \le 2$. However $L^1 \not\subseteq L^2$ because $1/\sqrt{x}\in L^1$ and $1/\sqrt{x}\notin L^2$.